# How to compose buttons in QScrollArea?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator

I'm creating dynamically unknown number of buttons and put them to QScrollArea.

```
someDialogButton = new QPushButton();
usersDialogs.push_back(someDialogButton);
ui->usersArea->setWidget(someDialogButton);
```

`usersDialogs` is `QVector<QPushButton*>`

`usersArea` is `QScrollArea`

But the buttons overlap and can be seen only the last button added. I tried use: `setLayout(QLayout* layout)` method, but it was useless.

How I can compose the buttons to make all buttons visible?

Comment: You need a container widget like QLable or QWidget to layout those button into (using a layout), then put the container into the scroll area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#setWidget) says

> ```
> void QScrollArea::setWidget(QWidget * widget)
> ```
>
> Sets the scroll area's *widget*.
>
> The *widget* becomes a child of the scroll area, and will be destroyed
>   when the scroll area is deleted or when a new widget is set.

Therefore, whenever you call `QScrollArea::setWidget()` you overwrite the previous widget. What you need to do is to fill a `QWidget` with the buttons and then you call `QScrollArea::setWidget()` on that container widget.

Here's an example, of what your classes constructor could look like:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) 
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    this->resize( 300, 200 );
    auto * layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    auto * scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable( true );
    layout->addWidget( scrollArea );
    auto * container = new QWidget();
    scrollArea->setWidget( container );
    layout = new QVBoxLayout(container);
    auto * button1 = new QPushButton( "1", container);
    auto * button2 = new QPushButton( "2", container);
    auto * button3 = new QPushButton( "3", container);
    layout->addWidget( button1 );
    layout->addWidget( button2 );
    layout->addWidget( button3 );
}
```

For me it gives this:

[image: Window shown by the application]

Comment: Why did you twice `layout` is assigned a value `new QVBoxLayout`?

Comment: @TiPo I need two layouts. One for the `MainWindow` which contains the `QScrollArea` and one for the `QWidget` containing the push buttons. I could have used two variables, but I didn't bother.